# How to add a loading animation while Fetch data from API? Vanilla js

Tags: javascript, css, api, promise, loading

I tried a lot of answers here, but all answers I found, people are using jquery, ajax, react or things like that. I would like a answer with pure javascript (vanilla js).

```
const movieApiMovies = () => {
fetch(movieApi_url + "movies/")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(function (data) {
        let result = `<h2> Movies I've watched! </h2>`;
        data.forEach((movie) => {
            const {id, name, year, note_imdb, genre, duration} = movie;
            result +=
                `<div>
                    <h5> Movie ID: ${id} </h5>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Movie name: ${name}</li>
                        <li>Movie year: ${year}</li>
                        <li>Movie note on IMDB: ${note_imdb}</li>
                        <li>Movie Genre: ${genre}</li>
                        <li>Movie duration: ${duration}</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>`;
            document.getElementById('movieResult').innerHTML = result;
        })
    })
};
```

I have a animation, it's on this Div element.

```
<div class="boxLoading"></div>
```

And I have a button that is going to call everything.

```
<div id="button1">
      <button class="button" id="moviesfromapi"onclick="movieApiMovies ()">Display</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I got promises errors trying to do it inside the fetch method, that's why I didn't post it. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

add loader before call and remove once you receive results, as follows

```
const movieApiMovies = () => {
let loader = `<div class="boxLoading"></div>`;
document.getElementById('movieResult').innerHTML = loader;
fetch(movieApi_url + "movies/")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(function (data) {
        let result = `<h2> Movies I've watched! </h2>`;
        data.forEach((movie) => {
            const {id, name, year, note_imdb, genre, duration} = movie;
            result +=
                `<div>
                    <h5> Movie ID: ${id} </h5>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Movie name: ${name}</li>
                        <li>Movie year: ${year}</li>
                        <li>Movie note on IMDB: ${note_imdb}</li>
                        <li>Movie Genre: ${genre}</li>
                        <li>Movie duration: ${duration}</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>`;
            document.getElementById('movieResult').innerHTML = result;
        })
    })
};
```

Comment: Thanks!! I was trying to do it inside the fetch and I was getting promises errors.